# Concise query for union same columns from multiple tables in HIVE

Tags: mysql, database, hive, hiveql

In hive, I have to read same columns from multiple tables and union them but the number of tables is high around 70 and its seems odd to write union over 70 tables. All the tables start with same alphabets e.g. ABC2018, ABC2019, Can we use wild cards? e.g.

```
select a, b, c
from ABC*
```

or there a way to concisely write the following query

```
select a, b, c
from ABC2018
union
select a, b, c
from ABC2019
....
....
....
upto 70 tables
```

Regards,

Comment: There is no such wildcard in SQL. You could use dynamic SQL to generate the query with 70 `UNION`s. Also this multiplcity of tables raises the question of your database normalisation... If this data was to be stored in a single table, the query would be straight-forward.

Comment: yes database normalization not in my hand, working with old databases.

Comment: UNION does also distinct, use UNION ALL, it is faster if you do need distinct